# How do I toggle the size of a DIV to extend its height when a link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a 'top bar' extend to reveal a series of links.

To do this, I have chosen jQuery and some research reveals I should toggle this.

Following many failed events at manipulating the class of the 'top bar', I have tried a different approach - see: http://jsfiddle.net/SQHQ2/2408/

The HTML:

```
<div id='topbar'>toggle me</div>
<a href="#" class="menu">Toggle</a>
```

The CSS:

```
#topbar {
    background: orange;
    color: white;
    height: 60px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

The jQuery:

```
    $(".menu").click(function() {
        $("#topbar").toggle(function() {
            $("#topbar").animate({
                height: 165
            }, 200);
        }, function() {
            $("#topbar").animate({
                height: 60
            }, 200);
        });
    });
```

When I try this code, it simply hides the top bar in an animated manner.

Could you help me to achieve a solution that, on the click of a link with class '.menu', will extend the 'top bar' DIV from a height of 60px to a height of 160px, to reveal the hidden links?

I welcome solutions achieved by alternative means, so long as they work :)

Best wishes for the new year and TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach to consider is to keep all your CSS and JavaScript separate. Here's an example of what I mean:

HTML

```
<div id='topbar'>toggle me</div>
<a href="#" class="menu">Toggle</a>
```

CSS

```
#topbar {
  background: orange;
  color: white;
  text-align:center;
}

.short {
  height: 60px;
}

.tall {
  height: 160px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(".menu").click(function() {
  $('#topbar').toggleClass('short', 'tall');
});
```

The idea is to keep your styles in your CSS and then toggle the classes you want applied.

Comment: This is the only viable solution in a productive environment imho.

Comment: I agree @th3falc0n, it keeps your JavaScript code from being convoluted with styling choices. It's much easier for me to think in terms of CSS classes and choosing which class to use as opposed to the specifics of the CSS rules.

Comment: Also it allows to deploy an alternative design without making changes to essential code, which could cause bugs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, I never thought of it from this perspective. Kudos! :)

I have a last question. Is there a way for me to have the top-bar start out as 'short'?

Answer (score 1):

```
.toggle
```

is a handler in jQuery, that toggles on click (that is why your bar toggles when you click it)

```
$(".menu").toggle(function() {
    $("#topbar").animate({
        height: 165
    }, 200);
}, function() {
    $("#topbar").animate({
        height: 60
     }, 200);
});
```

should work just fine.

Comment: When I load the page, this snippet of code causes the 'menu' button to disappear immediately, before I click it.

Comment: This doesn't happen in the JSFiddle so I can't reproduce your fault. http://jsfiddle.net/SQHQ2/2409/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".menu").toggle(function() {
    $("#topbar").animate({
        height: 165
    }, 200);
}, function() {
    $("#topbar").animate({
        height: 60
    }, 200);
});
```

Comment: When I load the page, this snippet of code causes the 'menu' button to disappear immediately, before I click it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can add an attribute to your a tag to keep the state (expanded/not-expanded). And instead of toggle just use it to animate your top bar

HTML

```
<div id='topbar'>toggle me</div>
<a expanded="0" href="javascript:void(0);" class="menu">Toggle</a>
```

JS

```
$(".menu").click(function() {
    var thisObj = this;
    var expanded = parseInt($(thisObj).attr("expanded"));
    if (expanded){
        $("#topbar").animate({height:60},200, function(){
            $(thisObj).attr("expanded", "0");    
        });
    } else {
        $("#topbar").animate({height:160},200, function(){
            $(thisObj).attr("expanded", "1");  
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Adding an `expanded` attr to the `<a>` results in invalid HTML. Using `data-expanded` would keep the HTML valid, but an even better solution would be using `aria-expanded`: http://www.marcozehe.de/2010/02/10/easy-aria-tip-5-aria-expanded-and-aria-controls/